# Computing the average curvature of a curve

Tags: vector-calculus, homework

> Compute the average curvature of the curve
>
> $\qquad r(t) = ⟨t \cos t,\, t \sin t⟩\ \mathrm{for}\ 0 ≤ t ≤ 2π$.
>
> Use Mathematica to arrive at an exact value and its numerical approximation. Please include a printout of any Mathematica that you use in this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This looks like a homework problem. Have you attempted to solve it? Please post the code that you tried.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a simple homework problem, I don't think it would fair to just hand you the whole answer, but here are some hints.

To compute an exact expression for the mean curvature, use [`ArcCurvature`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcCurvature.html) and[`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html).

When you have the exact expression, let us call it `avgCrv`, then you can get an approximate numerical value with

```
N[avgCrv]
```

> `0.561`

You can use the the above value to check your work.